IntelliJ build automatically is only partially generating the sources
I have a custom annotation and annotation processor that I use to generate Guice binding for the annotated class.
When I perform a Rebuild project using IntelliJ, all the Bindings are generated properly.
I have the Build project automatically in IntelliJ Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler enabled.
The build project automatically performs an incremental build. The incremental build compiles only the edited class which in turn overwrites the file with the Guice bindings with only the binding for the class that was edited/ were part of the incremental build and have the annotation.
Is there a way to generate bindings for all the annotated Classes or perform a full rebuild so that all the code gets generated? Or is there a way to change the configuration / change the annotation processor?

That looks like an Annotation Processor issue/limitation. If your Project uses Maven/Gradle you can delegate the build process to them. Would you be able to share the Project?
